# Pictorial Guide/Reference to all MathJax Symbols

Tags: support, mathjax, reference

All the symbols for MathJax are available [here](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/v1.1-latest/tex.html#supported-latex-commands). Howbeit, they don't depict the codes' images, so is there somewhere or something that does?

I am conscious of LATEX guides which do exhibit the images, but the problem is that LATEX is  a strict superset of MathJax. It'd be hamstrung to suss out by trial and error which ones aren't featured in MathJax.

Comment: Note that your link is to the (old) v1.1 docs, rather than the latest [v2.x docs](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html#supported-latex-commands).  In the newer version, there is a link to the site that Martin suggests below.

Answer (score 8):

There is a question on TeX.SE: [Where are the MathJax LaTeX symbols/environments documented?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49330/where-are-the-mathjax-latex-symbols-environments-documented).

One of the answers given there provides this link: http://www.onemathematicalcat.org/MathJaxDocumentation/TeXSyntax.htm (That page contains a lot of MathJax, so it really takes some time for it to render.)

Comment: Also, avoid opening it on an iPad or iPhone using Chrome. It's too big to handle.

Comment: @DanielR: Thank you. Would there be a shorter or faster version?